# Redux useSelect doesn't get all data as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I'm trying to print out data from my database. It's doing it all well by using hooks and without it so this time I tried to use redux and hooks to implement CRUD. But thats return an undefined every render. so I called the payload and it's an array of objects. I'm using redux, middleware Thunk and hooks. please can someone guide me to fix the issue.

here is the code bellow :

**Component.jsx**

```
import { retrieveCars } from '../action/cars.action'
    
     const cars = useSelector(state => state.cars);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
      
        useEffect(() => {
          dispatch(retrieveCars());
          


        });
 <tbody>
                    {cars &&
                      cars.map((data) =>
                        <tr key={data.idCars}>
                       
                        <th scope="row">{data.idCars}</th>  
                      
                      <td>{data.carName}</td>
                      <td>{data.carModel}</td>
                      <td>
                      <Link to={"/classement/update/" + data.idCars}
                        className="btn btn-info"
                        >
                        Edit
                       </Link>
                
                      <button  className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteC(data.idCars)}>
                        Remove
                      </button>
                        </td> 
                     
                      
                     
                      </tr>
                    )
                    }
                      
                
                  </tbody>
        **cars.action.js**
export const retrieveCars = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const res = await DataService.getAll();
  
      dispatch({
        type: RETRIEVE_CARS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

**Car Reducer:**

```
const initialState = [];
  
  function carReducer(cars = initialState, action) {

    const { type, payload } = action;
  
    switch (type) {    
      case RETRIEVE_CARS:


           return payload;
   default:
        return cars;
    }
```

**Store.js**

```
import rootReducer from '../reducers/carReducer';
const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

[image]

Comment: How did you define rootReducer?

Comment: @Erfan import rootReducer from '../reducers/carReducer'; its the car reducer in the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw you are using `carReducer` for `rootReducer`. And `carReducer` only has state is an array. So `state` is an empty array and `state.cars` is undefined.

Just update like this to get cars:

```
const cars = useSelector(state => state);
```

Comment: Yeah that's working but if I had many state so useSelector(state => state.cars); should works if yeah Why now it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

So because you use carReducer as the rootReducer of your store, the main state of app is the same as cars state, as Viet answered.

But if you need to cars be only a piece of total state, and your total state to have other properties (for example a loginState), you have to create a reducer for each part of state, and then create a rootReducer with **combineReducer**

lets say you have these two reducers for two states:

```
cars ====> carsReducer
login ===> loginReducer
```

then

```
const rootReducer=combineReducers({cars:carsReducer,login:loginReducer})
```

now if you want to access different parsts of state:

```
const cars = useSelector(state => state.cars);
const login = useSelector(state => state.login);
```